# Dúvida em select de sql

Tags: sql

Então ... Eu tenho uma tabela que tem uma `sequenc`, um `num`, uma `dt_inicial` e uma `dt_final`.
  Minha dúvida é: como fazer um `Select` que pegue os dados entre a `dt_inicial` e `dt_final` mostrando os `num` entre eles?

Exemplo de como desejo:

```
select * from tabela where dt_inicial => (valores entre eles) <=dt_final mostrando o num
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select * from tabela where 'data de pesquisa' BETWEEN dt_inicial AND dt_final
```

O * no select significa retorne todos os campos da tabela, e desde que dt_inicial e dt_final sejam do tipo data correto.

Caso queira somente o num

```
select num from tabela where 'data de pesquisa' BETWEEN dt_inicial AND dt_final
```

**Complemento da resposta**

Baseado no comentário que fez para resposta do @edgar-muniz-berlinck, se você passa dt_inicial e dt_final como parâmetros então sua tabela deve estar com a modelagem errada. 
Considerando que o correto seria sua tabela conter uma coluna de nome **dt_ocorrencia**, e recebendo *dt_inicial* e *dt_final* como parâmetros de pesquisa, seu sql seria:

```
select num from tabela where dt_ocorrencia BETWEEN dt_inicial and dt_final
```

Comment: a regra de negócio dele pode especificar que ele precisa saber o tempo decorrido na ocorrência, ou quando iniciou ou quando finalizou. não pode dizer que a modelagem está incorreta sem entender a mesma completamente. -1

Comment: ok, então deveria dizer que a pergunta está mal-formulada pois se a regra de negócio é esta que citou, deveria ser descrita na pergunta para que possamos mais facilmente auxiliar. Talvez eu tenha errado o uso do termo, e deveria ter dito, você deve ter se enganado em sua modelagem.

Answer (score 5):

```
select num
from tabela
where 
  'a data que voce quer' between data_inicial and data_final
```

Comment: Assim nesse caso ela seleciona a data que eu quero se ela estiver entre a data_inicial e final? Pois eu jogo elas como parametro!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar também `>=`, `<=` e o operador `AND`, porém você precisa repetir o campo pesquisado.

```
SELECT num FROM tabela 
WHERE 'data_pesquisa' => dt_inicial AND 'data_pesquisa' <= dt_final
```

Lembrando que é só mais forma de fazer.

Utilizando `BETWEEN`, como mostrado nas outras respostas, na minha opinião é muito mais elegante e gera o mesmo resultado.